# Appending DOM data to a row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use `after()` to place more DOM data (a `<table>`) after a `$('tr')`; I am noticing that the width of the new element changes the width of the tr's first td element. What can I do to prevent that?

```
$('#table tr').click(function(){
    $(this).after(table);
    $('#data').slideDown("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZLLb/1/

Comment: Not the solution, but your `table` variable contains a table with the ID `#data`. Everytime you click, a new one is going to be added. But ID's must be unique! Use a class instead.

Comment: You can't place a `table` element after a `tr`.  It's invalid markup.  You need to create a new `tr` with at least one `td` and place the `table` in that element.

Comment: It's not valid to have a `table` after a `<tr>`. It should be another row.   `$(this).after($(table).find("tr"));`

Comment: Even if the new table is encapsulated in a div?

Comment: @ryan When I write HTML emails, I prefer nesting tables than using too many `colspan` and `rowspan`, for more clarity. Is that bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments stated, you can't have a `table` element in that position, and you should not repeat id's.  You CAN, however, have multiple `tbody` elements, as well as multiple elements with the same class, which is likely the solution you are going for:

```
var table = '<tbody class="data" style="display:none;"><tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td>            <td>Test</td></tr></tbody>';

$('#table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  $(this).closest('tbody').after(table);
  $('.data').last().slideDown("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZLLb/3/